# How to solve difficulty at casting parent class to child one in .net?

Tags: .net, casting, parent-child

I have this:

```
public class ClientSession : TcpClient
{
    public int SessionGUID = 0;
}
```

And somewhere in server threads this:

```
ClientSession client = (ClientSession)tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient(); //cast failure
```

Ok, i understand that to cast like that, right side object must be instance of ClientSession (that possibly stored in pointer to base class)
but... how to construct ClientSession in that case?

I don't want to make ClientSession like this:

```
public class ClientSession
{
    public int SessionGUID = 0;
    public TcpClient client;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient` will return a `TcpClient` object and nothing else. The type of an object cannot be changed at runtime, so a direct conversion (that preserves object identity and data) is not possible.

I think composition (similar to your last code snippet) would be the best approach. You could enable conversion using cast syntax by implementing a custom conversion operator, but i would rather suggest using a constructor that takes a `TcpClient` here:

```
public ClientSession(TcpClient client) { /* ... */ }
```

so you could do this:

```
ClientSession client = new ClientSession(tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient());
```

Comment: this is not how i wanted it and i knew that i can't cast like that and i write it in main question, i just asked for a way to somehow cast it... since your answer is first, i accept it

Comment: @Kosmos You cannot, because there is no way to change the type of an object at runtime. Once you have a TcpClient, it stays one, so the only solution i see is constructing a ClientSession with a TcpClient as field.

Answer (score 0):

All `ClientSession` are of type `TcpClient`, but not all `TcpClient` are of type `ClientSession`. `tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()` returns object of `TcpClient`, and it cannot be used as `ClientSession`. Alternatively you can tweak your class as follows,

```
class ClientSession
{
    public ClientSession(TcpClient client) 
    {
        this.client = client;
    }
    public TcpClient client {get; set;}
    // your stuff here...
}
```